# BroadcastReceiver not called when screen locked in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

In my Application, when a notification arrives, the `BroadcastReceiver` is not called if the screen is locked.
But when screen is unlocked, the `BroadcastReceiver` is called and displays the notification.

I also put the following permission in my manifest:

```
android.permission.WAKE_LOCK
```

But still not working.

Comment: Depending on how you start your broadcastReceiver and what you on `onReceive()` you might need a wake up lock

Comment: Are you using alarm manager?

Comment: @Tarun no , broadcast receiver called by C2DM com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here's the code that works for me:

```
NotificationManager mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(...);
...
mManager.notify(0, notification);
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
wl.acquire(15000);
```

Make sure that you send the notification from your server with `delay_while_idle=0` (that's the default value), or the notification won't be sent by GCM until your device wakes up.

Comment: I got it working without the extra code, it was due to `delay_while_idle` set to true in my server.

Answer (score 1):

Open the Activity A which you want to start from onReceive(....) of BroadCastReceiver. Paste this in onCreate() of Activity A

```
 final Window win= getWindow();
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | 
          WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

Make sure you are not pasting it before setContentView(....)   :-)