# How to show push notifications when screen is locked

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, lockscreen

I have an app which receives push notifications from custom webserver using the new gcm api. Everything works fine. However, I want to display the notifications on the lock screen too.

I googled around and found this post, but it won't help: [Android how to show notification on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442670/android-how-to-show-notification-on-screen)

Is there any simple way to achieve this? Thanks for your help!

EDIT //

Here is some code.

In the GCMHandler I use this snippet to show the notification:

```
   private void sendNotification() {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", message);
    intent.putExtra("pbid", pbid);
    intent.putExtra("alarm", alarm);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(alarm ? getString(R.string.txt_alarm_message_title) : getString(R.string.txt_info_message_title))
                    .setContentText(message);

    // play alarm tone
    if (alarm) playRingtone();

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

And in the application's main activity I used the code from the post above:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
...
}
```

The problem is, that the notification is shown, but not available on the lock screen. If the screen is screen is locked, no push notification will be received ;(

Comment: what is the problem when you tried the link. Provide some code which you tried using flag

Comment: I posted the code in the edit of my original post.

Comment: possible duplicate of [BroadcastReceiver not called when screen locked in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18481641/broadcastreceiver-not-called-when-screen-locked-in-android)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it out but it still doesn't work on Android 4.4.2 ;-( Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @Robin : Hello, have you find the answer for this question?

Answer (score -2):

try this it will work it.

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;

    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
                .setContentTitle("New mail from " + " ")
                .setContentText(msg).setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setDefaults(1).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.gcm_cloud).build();
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
                | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");
        wl.acquire(15000);

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, noti);

    }
```

Comment: This will only wake up the phone. The OP is asking how to show the notification when the screen is locked.

Comment: its display for lock screen notification just try this. then comment.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Question is how to show notification on Lock screen page, not in notification bar system.